# Solve pde problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

For each of the following PDE. (a) solve the characteristic equation (b) define a transformation of the PDE. And obtain the transformed equation. (c) find the general solution of the transformed equation.

$$xu_x-yu_y+u =x $$
Let $r=r(r,s) ,s=s (r,s) $
Char. eq. :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac {-y}{x} $$
$$\frac{dy}{y}= \frac {-dx}{x} $$
$$lny =-lnx + c$$
$$s=c =lnx+lny=lnxy $$
let r=x
$$u_x=u_r +\frac {u_s}{x}$$
$$u_y=0 +\frac {u_s}{y}$$

Substitute in eq.$(r=x,s=lnxy)$
$$ru_r+u_s -u_s+u =r $$
$$ru_r+u=r $$
First one homogeneous  eq
$$u_r+\frac {u}{r}=0$$
$$M= exp ( \int (1/r))=r$$

$$ru_r+u=0$$
$$u = \frac {F (s)}{r}=\frac{F (lnxy) }{x}$$

How to find nonhomogenes  for this problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$ru_r+u=r$$
You want the solution for this equation ? 
$$r\frac {du}{dr}+u=r$$
$$(ru)'=r$$
Just integrate
$$ru=\int rdr=\frac {r^2}2+K(s)$$
$$u=\frac 1r( \frac {r^2}2+K(s))$$
$$\boxed{u(r,s)=\frac {K(s)}r+ \frac {r}2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x u_x-y u_y=x-u$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}=\frac{du}{x-u}$$
A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{-y}$
$$xy=c_1$$
A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{x-u}=\frac{-dx+2du}{-x+2(x-u)}=\frac{d(-x+2u)}{-(-x+2u)}$
$$x(-x+2u)=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE :
$$x(-x+2u)=\Phi(xy)$$
$$u(x,y)=\frac12\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\Phi(xy) \right)$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the boundary conditions.